# when I click the user form in vba It always show the path/file error and I can not see the object of the userform where I am doing wrong?

Tags: vba

```
Private cancel As Boolean


Public Function ShowDatesDialog(startDate As Date, endDate As Date, timeInterval As String) As Boolean

Call Initialize

Me.Show

If Not cancel Then

    startDate = calStartDate.Value
    endDate = calEndDate.Value
    Select Case True
        Case optMonth: timeInterval = "m"
        Case optWeek: timeInterval = "w"
        Case optDay: timeInterval = "d"
    End Select
End If
ShowDatesDialog = Not cancel

Unload Me

End Function

Private Sub Initialize()

calStartDate.Value = DateSerial(Year(Date) - 2, Month(Date), Day(Date))

calEndDate.Value = Date

optMonth.Value = True

End Sub

Private Function Valid() As Boolean

Dim startDate As Date, endDate As Date

Valid = True

startDate = calStartDate.Value

endDate = calEndDate.Value

If startDate >= endDate Then

    Valid = False
    MsgBox "The starting date should be before the ending date.", _
    vbInformation, "Invalid dates"
    calStartDate.SetFocus
    Exit Function
    ElseIf startDate < EARLIST_DATE Then
    Valid = False
    MsgBox " The starting date shouldn't be before 1990.", _
    vbInformation, "Start date too early"
    calStartDate.SetFocus
    Exit Function
    ElseIf endDate > Date Then
    Valid = False
    masgbox " The ending date shouldn't be after today's date.", _
    vbInformation, "end date too late"
    calEndDate.SetFocus
    Exit Function
End If

End Function

Private Sub btnOK_Click()

    If Valid Then Me.Hide

    cancel = False

End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click()

Me.Hide

cancel = True

End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then btnCancel_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: The only way I could imagine you'd be getting an error when clicking the userform is if there's code in the `UserForm_Click` event or the `UserForm_Activate` event.  Do you have code in either one of those events?

Answer (score 0):

Lots.

`Initialize` and `btnCancel_Click` are event handlers: they should never be called explicitly. Their purpose is to *handle events*.

You're on the right path though - I see you're trying really hard to avoid using the default instance... yet I suspect your calling code looks like this:

```
MyAwesomeForm.ShowDatesDialog startDate, endDate, timeInterval
```

Right?

Well that `ShowDatesDialog` is running off the form's *default instance*, which means this:

```
Me.Show
```

Displays the default instance.

A form shouldn't be responsible for destroying itself (because it's not creating itself) - you did good with `Me.Hide`, but `Unload Me` then defeats all of it, because it makes the object self-destruct, which means the callers can never get a grasp on the object: they display the form, and then it disappears and the object is gone before they can do anything with it.

A form shouldn't be responsible for *showing* itself either: that's the caller's job too.

Expose the encapsulated `cancel` field as a read-only property, and rename it to `cancelled`, so that it doesn't clash with the `QuerClose` handler's parameter:

```
Private cancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = cancelled
End Property
```

Expose your *model* as properties too:

```
Public Property Get StartingDate() As Date
    StartingDate = calStartDate.Value
End Property

Public Property Get EndingDate() As Date
    EndingDate = calEndDate.Value
End Property

Public Property Get TimeInterval() As String
    Select Case True
        Case optMonth.Value
            TimeInterval = "m"

        Case optWeek.Value
            TimeInterval = "w"

        Case optDay.Value
            TimeInterval = "d"

        Case Else
            TimeInterval = vbNullString
    End Select
End Property
```

And now your callers can do this - basically your `ShowDatesDialog` function becomes the calling code:

```
With New MyAwesomeForm
    .Show
    If Not .IsCancelled Then

        Dim startDate As Date
        startDate = .StartingDate

        Dim endDate As Date
        endDate = .EndingDate

        Dim interval As String
        interval = .TimeInterval

    End If
End With
```

The `Valid` function should be a verb, e.g. `Validate`, or *start* with a verb, e.g. `IsValid`; because the function has side-effects, I'd be more inclined to name it `Validate` than `IsValid`, but YMMV. Its indentation seriously needs some love, though:

```
If startDate >= endDate Then

    Valid = False
    MsgBox "The starting date should be before the ending date.", _
    vbInformation, "Invalid dates"
    calStartDate.SetFocus
    Exit Function

ElseIf startDate < EARLIST_DATE Then

    Valid = False
    MsgBox " The starting date shouldn't be before 1990.", _
    vbInformation, "Start date too early"
    calStartDate.SetFocus
    Exit Function

ElseIf endDate > Date Then

    Valid = False
    masgbox " The ending date shouldn't be after today's date.", _
    vbInformation, "end date too late"
    calEndDate.SetFocus
    Exit Function

End If
```

Note, if VBA lets you run this code without complaining at compile-time, then you need to specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module (should be at the top of *every* module), because this can't possibly compile:

> ```
>    masgbox " The ending date shouldn't be after today's date.", _
>     vbInformation, "end date too late"
> ```

Unless you have a `masgbox` function defined somewhere, of course. Consider reducing redundancies by inverting the Boolean logic (a Boolean variable is `False` until it's assigned to `True`), extracting a `message` variable and standardizing the title, and only calling a `MsgBox` in one place.

---

To be clear, here's your form's code-behind as I see it:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const EARLIEST_DATE As Date = #1990-01-01#
Private cancelled As Boolean

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = cancel
End Property

Public Property Get StartingDate() As Date
    StartingDate = calStartDate.Value
End Property

Public Property Get EndingDate() As Date
    EndingDate = calEndDate.Value
End Property

Public Property Get TimeInterval() As String
    Select Case True
        Case optMonth.Value
            TimeInterval = "m"

        Case optWeek.Value
            TimeInterval = "w"

        Case optDay.Value
            TimeInterval = "d"

        Case Else
            TimeInterval = vbNullString
    End Select
End Property

Private Sub Initialize()        
    calStartDate.Value = DateSerial(Year(Date) - 2, Month(Date), Day(Date))
    calEndDate.Value = Date
    optMonth.Value = True        
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then 
        cancelled = True
        Me.Hide
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    cancelled = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub btnOk_Click()
    If Validate Then Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Function Validate() As Boolean

    Dim result As Boolean
    Dim message As String

    If StartingDate >= EndingDate Then

        message = "Invalid selection. The starting date must be before the ending date.", 
        calStartDate.SetFocus

    ElseIf StartingDate < EARLIEST_DATE Then

        message = "Start date is too early. Cannot be before 1990."
        calStartDate.SetFocus

    ElseIf EndingDate > Date Then

        message = "End date is too late. The ending date cannot be after today's date."
        calEndDate.SetFocus

    Else
        result = True
    End If

    If Not result Then MsgBox message, "Validation Failed", vbExclamation
    Validate = result

End Function
```

And the calling code:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    With New MyAwesomeForm

        .Show
        If Not .IsCancelled Then

            Dim startDate As Date
            startDate = .StartingDate

            Dim endDate As Date
            endDate = .EndingDate

            Dim interval As String
            interval = .TimeInterval

            '...do stuff...

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Consider handling the `calStartDate` and `calEndDate` controls' `Changed` event to perform earlier validation, and only enable the <kbd>OK</kbd> button when the form is valid; that way you can replace the annoying message boxes by a neat little validation/notification label.

---

That said I've no idea what your path/file error comes from, nothing in your post does anything with any files. But this should help you get your forms straight at least.